# Change element style in custom css WP

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WP where i want to change an element style.

This is what i have in console when i inspect with firebug:

```
<div class="et_pb_container clearfix" style="min-height: 400px;">
```

And then on the right in Styles i have

```
element.style {
min-height: 400px;
}
```

How can i change the element.style in the custom CSS editor?

I want min-height to be 550px;

When i try with

```
et_pb_container.clearfix{
min-height: 550px;
}
```

Nothing happens.....

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your stylesheet:

```
.et_pb_container.clearfix[style] {
  min-height: 550px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.et_pb_container.clearfix{
    min-height: 550px !important;
}
```

Or change min-height in inline style:

```
<div class="et_pb_container clearfix" style="min-height: 550px;">
```

Inline styles usually take precedence over css stylesheets, unless you specify !important keyword.

http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/